# how to place a line of text below the end of grid

Tags: android

I have a task to show images in grid ,i got the view what i needed but i have to place  **click here to view more..** at bottom.

Here i'm facing problem to place the text below image has a common,
for example,each row have three images in grid and it looks:

```
    ----------------------
   | img1   img2   img3
   | img4    ...   ...
   | 
   | click here to view more..
```

after img3, img4 in next row in the grid

How can i place text in the view has like above?

here my code for `imageview.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="100dip" android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="80dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/jr_lb_list_icon" android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_height="65dip"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="@drawable/border"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here my code for `imageview.xml`:

```
<merge android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="340dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <GridView 
                    android:id="@+id/jr_lookbook_grid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="320dip" android:numColumns="4"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"            
                    android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"
                    />                      
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:text="Next" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/gold"/>
</merge>
```

Please, help me to get  the text below, I tried to put layout for textview but i can't get view what i need.anybody help me get it...

Comment: friend, i can't get you what you edited here,please mention where u edited,now i got the view with text at end of grid ,but during next click event it have to parse next set of images from page2 url and set it into grid,it contains first page images with clickevent image from url2,but the focus is only on first url image during scrool only i can able to view url2 images in grid but i need to focus on url2 images and when i scroll up only i nedd to view prevous images,how can i get it,if focused next url image i may think it will visible at bottom,back ground of click event thread asynctask hv

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use the Merge Layout thats proposed in the Android Dev guide.

I have tried this out briefly using a GridView and TextView and has worked Pretty well.

here is my code for merge.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<GridView 
       android:id = "@+id/gridview"
       android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
       android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
       android:columnWidth = "90dp"
       android:numColumns = "auto_fit"
       android:verticalSpacing = "10dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing = "10dp"
       android:stretchMode = "columnWidth"
       android:gravity = "center"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="Want to see more?" />
</merge>
```

In your Activity class you should do the following:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.merge);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

note: ImageAdapter is a custom adapter used to display images. Now Using some random pictures you can generate the following [view](http://www.flickr.com/photos/58348205@N03/5357357286/).

Obviously you would need to change the TextView to some sort of a button and maybe disable any scrolling in the GridView for your idea to work well.